# Rails 7/Action Cable: Access consumer instance from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-7

On Rails 7, I have created a channel called "SessionChannel". When my page loads, the consumer is being properly created as I can see the log show in the browser.

This is my app/javascript/channels/session_channel.js:

```
import consumer from "channels/consumer"

var channel = consumer.subscriptions.create("SessionChannel", {                           
  connected() {
    console.log("Connected to session channel");                                    
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    console.log("got data: " + data);
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  channel.send({ some_data_to_rails: "goes_here" })
  console.log("sent");
}, 3000);
```

This works fine and the `channel.send` properly sends data back up the channel. But it seems I can only access the `channel` variable inside this file. If I try to access it in the browser or the application.js for example, it's undefined.

**The question**: Is it possible to export this variable (consumer/channel instance) to the app-wide javascript scope? So that I can `channel.send` from any view? Or at least be able to do it in the browser?

Comment: Yes, its possible to set globals either though `window` or whatever mechanism the assets pipeline in use uses. Don't know why you would want to that though as you can brodcast to a channel from the controller. If you want to be able to use this code from your `application.js` you can make this into a proper module and import it.

Comment: @max sorry when you say "broadcast to a channel from the controller" do you mean the stimulus controller? Because broadcasting to a channel from a rails controller isn't what I'm going for here: I'd like to broadcast from client -> server -> back to other clients. I've tried making it a module: https://pastebin.com/MerAxQm4 
I then imported that file in application.js but the class still isn't in scope...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it from a browser console and from inline scripts if you add it to window:

```js
const channel = consumer.subscriptions.create("SessionChannel", {
  // ...
});

window.channel = channel;
```

---

However, that's not necessary:

```js
// app/javascript/channels/session_channel.rb

import consumer from "channels/consumer";

// NOTE: make sure to export it
export default consumer.subscriptions.create("SessionChannel", {
  received(data) {
    console.log("SessionChannel", data);
  },
});
```

```rb
# app/channels/session_channel.rb

class SessionChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "session_channel"
  end

  def receive(data)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "session_channel", data
  end
end
```

You can create a stimulus controller to make it "accessible from the veiw":

```
// app/javascript/controllers/hello_controller.rb

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

// NOTE: now you have something to import
//       you are working with modules, so `sessionChannel`
//       will only be available in this file, if you need it
//       somewhere else then you have to import it there as well.
import sessionChannel from "channels/session_channel";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["message"];

  send(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    sessionChannel.send({ message: this.messageTarget.value });
    this.messageTarget.value = "";
  }
}
```

Use it in any view:

```html
<!-- app/views/home/index.html.erb -->

<div data-controller="hello">
  <%= text_area_tag :message, "", data: { hello_target: "message" } %>
  <%= button_tag "say: hello", data: { action: "hello#send" } %>
</div>
```

---

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import*

Comment: This is *Precisely* what I wanted. Thanks so much!