# How to setup actioncable in rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-7

I have been trying to get Rails 7 application for days to no avail. I have tried many tutorials, many of which have been outdated, and gotten no useful results. I tried ChatGPT for quite a while to no avail as well. steps I have taken:

1. `rails generate channel chat_room`
2. have this in the app/channels/chatroom_channel.rb file §

```
# app/channels/chatroom_channel.rb
class ChatroomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def connected
    console.log("Connected to Actioncable")
  end

  def disconnected
    # Logic when a client disconnects from the channel
  end

  def received(data)
    # Logic when a client receives data from the channel
  end
end
```

3. added this in the routes file :

```
  mount ActionCable.server => "/cable"
```

4. started rails server.
5. looked at the javascript console to the message "connected to
   actioncable"

6.I don't see a message

Comment: you have javascript embedded in your ruby code. This is wrong. You need to write the javascript to be embedded into the view to create the consumer and subscriber for the channel. The ActionCable guide lays it out pretty well: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

Comment: Do you actually have ActionCable or WebSocket JS setup on the client-side to connect to the `/cable` route? Do you have `config/cable.yml` setup for the development environment?

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
# Rails 7.0.6
rails new hello_cable -c tailwind
cd hello_cable
bin/rails g channel chat
bin/rails g scaffold Message content
bin/rails db:migrate
open http://localhost:3000/messages
bin/dev
```

```rb
# app/channels/chat_channel.rb

class ChatChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "the_chat"
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/controllers/messages_controller.rb

def create
  @message = Message.create(message_params)
  ActionCable.server.broadcast("the_chat", @message)
  head :ok
end
```

```js
// app/javascript/channels/chat_channel.js

import consumer from "channels/consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("ChatChannel", {
  connected() {
    console.log("connected")
  },
  received(data) {
    const messages = document.querySelector("#messages")
    messages.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<p>${data.content}</p>`)
    messages.lastElementChild.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
  }
})
```

```rb
# app/views/messages/index.html.erb

<%= tag.div do %>
  <%= tag.div id: "messages", class: "h-96 overflow-auto" do %>
    <% Message.last(10).each do |message| %>
      <%= tag.p message.content %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form_with model: Message.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "message..." %>
    <%= f.submit "send", class: "p-2 font-bold" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

Also, like that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75728527/207090

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75808949/207090